# Fix For React onDragExit and onDrop Events Not Working In Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I have created a **div** to enable me to **drag and drop files**. When you drag file over the div, the **onDragEnter** React event fires with no problem.

However **onDragExit** event does not fire when you drag out of div. Also  **onDrop** event does not fire when you drop the file therefore the browser opens the file even if you add the e.preventDefault() in the onDrop handler.

I have searched over the internet for fixes and non seems to work. Others claim is a bug in Chrome e.t.c.

The code below is the code in index.js. 
You can also check the full sample project code and edit it on **Stackblitz** at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fnkaqk?file=index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

  const handleOnDragEnter = (event) => {

    console.log("draged enter");
  };

  const handleOnDragExit = (event) => {

    console.log("drag exit");
  };

  const handleOnDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("droped");
  };

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Drag File And Drop</h1>

    <div style={{height: "100px", backgroundColor: "purple"}} onDrop={handleOnDrop} onDragEnter={handleOnDragEnter} onDragExit={handleOnDragExit}></div>
  </>
  )
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is weird problem with different browsers, one thing you should change is change OnDragExit to OnDragLeave

as the definition given in docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

With the other thing to stop drop to download file, what I have done in past is to prevent default on both onDrop and onDragOver

```
<div
    id="source"
    style={{ height: "100px", backgroundColor: "purple" }}
    onDragOver={handleOnDrop}
    onDrop={handleOnDrop}
    onDragEnter={handleOnDragEnter}
    onDragLeave={handleOnDragExit}
  ></div>
```